# Auto discovery of DAAP share through SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, rhythmbox, tunnel, daap

I got a remote machine (somewhere else on the internet) serving my music via DAAP through forked-daapd.

I SSH to the remote machine, tunnelling remote port 3689 to local port 3689 (which is the default DAAP port).

On the local machine, when I start Rhythmbox, it doesn't auto discover the "local" DAAP share. I'm able to add it manually, but that's a tedious task, as I have to do it every time I start Rhythmbox.

My question is: What do I need to do to get Rhythmbox to auto discover the DAAP share?

Alternatively, is there some kind of Rhythmbox conf file where I can add the DAAP share permanently?

Answer (score 1):

I belive daap discovery is a layer2 service. Which means it's broadcast.
Which means you have to be on the same network. Just forwarding one port wont "catch" the broadcasts.

You would have to create a layer2 vpn. This could be done with software like openvpn or vtund. But there has to be simpler ways.

What is it that you really want to do? Listen to music from your remote machine?

why not just mount the remote filesystem on your remote box with sshfs , and just play files like they were local?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try using VPN when I get some time. Somebody on Twitter also suggested that.

sshfs was my first idea. but as this is done over the internet, it takes an unacceptably long time for Rhythmbox to index the (10,000+) files. That's why I started looking at DAAP.

(As I'm a Squeezebox owner, running the Logitech Media Server software on the machine with the music, I actually started out trying to use SoftSqueeze. But the current release has some rendering problems, making it is far from usable. But that's way off topic for this question.)

Comment: youre welcome, just make sure its some kind of point to point vpn that's bridging, not routing. I would say that most VPNs are routing by default.